# How do I create a project in kivy running on android?

Tags: android, python, kivy

I'm trying to understand [kivy](http://kivy.org/docs/index.html). After installation, launching kivy, I got a message saying I should create a project first in `/mny/sdcard/kivy`. The folder didn't exist so I created it via FTP connection. I then placed a `main.py` file in a subfolder. launching kivy again (After forcing it to close) yield the same result. What am I missing?

Answer (score 7):

Be careful. You're using one possible method to run Kivy-based software, using the [Kivy launcher](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android.html#packaging-your-application-for-kivy-launcher). This launcher require you to install your application (`main.py`) and a description file (`android.txt`) in a directory `kivy/yourapp` on your sdcard.

So in `/mnt/sdcard` OR `/sdcard`, ensure you have a `kivy` directory + a directory for your application + `main.py` + `android.txt`.

If you want to create a standalone APK, then you need to use [python-for-android](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android.html#packaging-your-application-into-apk) project.